# Rspec for a ordering using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, will-paginate

I'm having a bad time trying to run my `rspec` test. The problem seems with the following line:

```
expect(assigns(:posts).count).to eq 2
```

I got 0, but was expected 2.

My **rspec** test:

```
RSpec.describe Portfolio::BlogController, type: :controller do
  let(:posts) {build_stubbed_list(:post, 2)}
  let(:post) {build_stubbed :post}

  specify '#index' do
    expect(Post).to receive(:paginate).with(page: '2').ordered.
                           and_return( posts.paginate(per_page: 2) )
    get :index, page: 2

    expect(assigns(:posts).count).to eq 2
    expect(response).to render_template 'index'
  end
end
```

My **controller**:

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

If I removed the `order` from my controller and `ordered` from my test everything is ok. Any idea?

Comment: What does your `build_stubbed_list` factory look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved adding the following to my model:

```
default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }
```

The `ordered` action wasn't neccesary in my test.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [`receive_message_chain`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains).